# Anyone using RTMP on CloudFront? I can't specify a crossdomain.xml file

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cross-domain, rtmp

I'm using a streaming distribution on `CloudFront` to serve media via `RTMP`.

Obviously I want to restrict the `crossdomain.xml` file but `CloudFront` is only serving it's default one.

The docs give instruction on how to overwrite their `default ->` I have a public, non-restricted `crossdomain.xml` in the root of my `s3 bucket` (the one with the media files), but it still serves out the default. What am I missing?

The default should not be served here:
http://sixqlk56v2jbq.cloudfront.net/crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 2):

The Adobe Flash Media Server crossdomain.xml file specifies which domains can access media files in a particular domain. CloudFront supplies a default file that allows all domains to access the media files in your streaming distribution, and you cannot change this behavior. If you include a more restrictive crossdomain.xml file in your Amazon S3 bucket, CloudFront ignores it. So that means that you actually can not have your own crossdomain.xml file.